# Trouble installing Python 3.7.3 via pyenv on macOS 13.0.1 with Rosetta

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyenv, rosetta

I have an iTerm instance configured to run with Rosetta, using homebrew (x86 version) and pyenv (x86 version) but when I try to run `pyenv86 install 3.7.3` I still get the following:

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.0.1 using python-build 20180424)
```

More specifically in the logs:

```
checking for clang++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I have the following setup:

```
$ arch 
i386
```

```
$ which brew86
brew86: aliased to arch --x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew
```

```
$ which pyenv86
pyenv86: aliased to arch -x86_64 pyenv
```

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/abhinavmulagada/.pyenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

This is what my `~/.zshrc` looks like:

```
# rosetta setup
if [ $(arch) = "i386" ]; then
        alias brew86='arch --x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew'
        alias pyenv86="arch -x86_64 pyenv"
fi

# pyenv
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

path=('/opt/homebrew/bin' $path)
export PATH
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, been stuck on this for a while.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turns out that python 3.7.3 isn't compatible with OS X 13.0.1. The latest version I could get to work is 3.7.10